# Push view controller when cell is tapped

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift

I have tableViewController which pulls data from Parse. This calls inherits from UINavigationControllerDelegate.

I want to push a new view controller when the user taps on a cell. It seems like a simple task but I can't get it to work. I have first tried just simply making a push segue in my storyboard but nothing happens when I tap on the cell. I have tried to do it programmatically but the app crashes when I tap on the cell. I get a breakpoint error on the instantiation line:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Parse


class PFViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let vc: Podcast = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Podcast") as Podcast
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Why does the app crash? The error message should tell you exactly what the problem is. Perhaps your identifier doesn't match any identifier in the storyboard. Maybe it does but it isn't a Podcast.

Comment: The identifier is good. I had given it to the navigation controller and not the VC it's embedding. works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the segue, ctrl-drag from the TableViewController to the destination viewController:

[image]

Then select the segue and give it an identifier in the property inspector:

[image]

Now you are able to perform this segue in code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: cell)
}
```